# Why is System.Type arguments chosen over generics in some classes of .NET framework?

Tags: .net, generics

I've noticed that several built-in classes/methods in .NET framwork takes an argument of System.Type where (in my opinion) it would have been cleaner to use generics.
For example, to create a DataContractSerializer instance I need to write

```
var s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyCustomClass));
```

instead of

```
var s = new DataContractSerializer<MyCustomClass>();
```

I'm not looking for a debate on which way is the "best", I'm rather curios to know whether there are any good reasons for doing either way. :)

Some more examples (taken from my head) are:
- System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer (constructor)
- System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost (constructor and a couple of methods)
- System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderAttribute

Comment: Generics weren't added until .Net 2.0, so they weren't available for earlier classes.

Comment: Two other lessons I learned the hard way on this subject: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/cf-woes.html and http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/compact-framework-woes-revisted.html

Comment: Marc: Interesting reading, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two classes in your example - XmlSerializer and ServiceHost - were designed before generics existed. Presumably Microsoft could invent replacements for these classes that deal in generics, but this hasn't happened.

Generics often aren't essential: if a method's signature doesn't depend on the type, then it shouldn't make any difference to the caller whether they pass `typeof(MyCustomClass)` or call `Method<MyCustomClass>`. Having a System.Type argument is often more useful: if you're writing your own reflection code, you'll normally have a System.Type anyway. If all you've got is a System.Type, then calling a generic method is much harder.

Comment: Thanks! The pre-date explanation is ofcource obvious (even though I didn't mentioned it) but the other reason makes good sense. Accepted because you were one minute faster than Marc :)

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `XmlSerializer`, it pre-dates generics, which is a good reason - but there are others. Having spent a *lot* of time on serialization code, I know painfully that (very common in library code) often *all you have is the `Type`*. Simply, library code like WCF can't be generic throughout - it would be a lot of overhead and complexity. For example, it might have just looked up the `Type` from the element-name (or some other marker). It didn't know the type in advance, so it can't possibly be "generic" (in the `<T>` sense).

In those cases when you have a `Type`, you can use `MakeGenericMethod` etc, but that is a lot of overhead, and can actually break CF etc (you start getting missing-method errors eventually).

As it happens, I have recently rewritten an entire serialization library from using generics as the primary API to using `Type` as the primary API. Fortunately this means the old methods just use `typeof(T)` with the new methods, so it works nicely.